# Overriding Global cache setting in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a ASP.Net MVC5 application. I disabled caching through out the application by applying global filter as follows:

```
public class CachingFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache); // HTTP 1.1.
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.AppendCacheExtension("no-store, must-revalidate");

        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Expires", "0"); // HTTP 1.0.
    }
}
```

The filter above disables caching brilliantly. But now I have an action to populate some statistics as a PartialView. For test purposes I wanted to enable caching for 20 seconds, by applying OutputCacheAttribute as follows:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    [OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.Client, Duration = 20, VaryByParam = "*")]
    public PartialViewResult Statistics()
    {
        var stats = GetStatistics();
        return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_Statistics.cshtml", stats);
    }
```

No matter what I did, If CachingFilter is enabled in application global, Statistics() method is always called even though 20 second period isn't elapsed. If I disable CachingFilter from global, Statistics() method is cached properly.

I thought/read that applying cache filter to action is the final verdict for caching. How to bypass global caching properties in action level without adding action/controller name in if clauses in global cache filter?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own attribute to exclude the global filter on certain attributes, for example, create a stub attribute:

```
public class ExcludeCacheFilterAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

Now in `CachingFilter` check for this attribute before running your code:

```
public class CachingFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ExcludeCacheFilterAttribute), false).Any())
        {
            return;
        }            

        //Carry on with the rest of your usual caching code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @DavidG, thanks for your effort but that doesn't helped. I tried to apply ExcludeCacheFilterAttribute to Controller too but I still cannot cache my Action.

Comment: So did you try to debug it? Does it exit the `OnActionExecuting` method before sending the cache detail correctly?